# how to determine the multiples of numbers in java

Tags: java

read 2 numbers and determine whether the first one is a multiple of second one.

Comment: Is this your homework ?

Comment: try your best and post your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (first % second == 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 9):

Given that this is almost certainly a homework question...

The first thing you need to think about is how you would do this if you didn't have a computer in front of you. If I asked you "is 8 a multiple of 2", how would you go about solving it? Would that same solution work if I asked you "is 4882730048987" a multiple of 3"?

If you've figured out the math which would allow you to get an answer with just a pen and paper (or even a pocket calculator), then the next step is to figure out how to turn that into code.

Such a program would look a bit like this:

- Start
- Read in the first number and store it
- Read in the second number and store it
- Implement the solution you identified in paragraph two using the mathematical operations, and store the result
- Print the result to the user.

Comment: Bravo for taking the time to give hints without revealing too much, and suggesting a methodology to solve problems beyond just this one case. Good mentality towards students / education

Comment: I just search operator to determine the multiples of numbers. Not a student and this question is useful for my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
//To check if num1 is a multiple of num2

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class multiples {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number!");
            int num1 = reader.nextInt();
            reader.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter another number!");
            int num2 = reader.nextInt();

            if ((num1 % num2) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Yes! " + num1 + " is a multiple of " + num2 + "!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No! " + num1 + " is not a multiple of " + num2 + "!");
            }
            reader.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A number `x` is a multiple of `y` if and only if the reminder after dividing `x` with `y` is `0`.

In Java the modulus operator(`%`) is used to get the reminder after the division. So `x % y` gives the reminder when `x` is divided by `y`.